# Custom container view controller - Instrument seeing a memory leak when adding a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I have made a custom container controller that consist of switching between two controllers. By the time i am adding the view of the first controller to my container controller, Instrument is showing me a memory leak. I currently have the following implementation:

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SCLDefaultSwitchViewController : UIViewController
{
@protected
    __weak UIViewController *_activeController;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak, readonly) UIViewController *activeController;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *leftViewController;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *rightViewController;
```

@end

**.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set-up content container view
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"left" sender:self];
    NSAssert( (_leftViewController != nil) , @"left view controller shouldn't be nil!");
    _activeController = _leftViewController;

    [self addChildViewController:_activeController];
    [self.view addSubview:_activeController.view];   // ---> memory leak here!!!!!
    [_activeController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"right" sender:self];
    NSAssert( (_rightViewController != nil) , @"right view controller shouldn't be nil!");
    [self addChildViewController:_rightViewController];
    [_rightViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    //[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performBackgroundTasks) withObject:nil];
}
```

I am making sure that the view is properly removed from its superview when switching between the two views:

```
- (void) didTapOnStartButton:(SCLSplashScreenViewController *)sender
{
    //CGRect originFrame   = _contentContainerView.bounds;
    CGRect originFrame   = self.view.bounds;
    CGRect offsetFrame   = originFrame;
    offsetFrame.origin.x =  originFrame.size.width;

    UIViewController* toViewController   = self.rightViewController;
    UIViewController* fromViewController = self.leftViewController;

    toViewController.view.frame = offsetFrame;

    __weak SCLSwitchViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                      toViewController:toViewController
                              duration:.4f
                               options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                            animations:^{
                                weakSelf.rightViewController.view.frame = originFrame;
                            }

                            // remove the splash screen controller when the animation is finished and delete it: we don't need it anymore
                            completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                if (finished){
                                    [weakSelf.leftViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
                                    [weakSelf.leftViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                                    [weakSelf.leftViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                                    weakSelf.leftViewController = nil;
                                    weakSelf.activeController = toViewController;
                                }
                            }];
}
```

I really don't see any good reason it should leak: any idea?

Comment: Do you know what object is leaking ?

Comment: I just saw a redline in instrument for the line i mentioned when using the callTree session

Comment: Can i know from there which object is leaking?

Comment: the leaks command tools should helps you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html :)

Comment: @Francescu thanks i need to dig into this

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding the new viewControllers again? If the segue is set up in Storyboard with the correct identifier, then you shouldn't need to add the childViewControllers manually. Leave this to the segue. Try changing your code to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// set-up content container view
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"left" sender:self];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"right" sender:self];

//[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performBackgroundTasks) withObject:nil];
}
```

And then in 'prepareForSegue:' set your Active VC to be the LeftVC not using your global objects but the 'destinationViewController' of the segue itself. That said, it's a little confusing why you do this so a little more information on what you're trying to achieve would be helpful.

Mike.

Comment: No i don't add any childcontroller when i am performing my custom segue

Answer (score 0):

To determine what is happening with your code we would need to see what exactly is inside View Propery. But not from your weak Reference but from your _leftViewController. Since its the active controller and its the first controller you added your leak its Inside that actual class, and not just the addition of that view.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"left" sender:self];
NSAssert( (_leftViewController != nil) , @"left view controller shouldn't be nil!");
_activeController = _leftViewController; /**Check Inside _leftViewController. **/

[self addChildViewController:_activeController];
[self.view addSubview:_activeController.view];   // ---> memory leak here!!!!!
```

We need to see your code INSIDE _leftViewController to determine what is going on. What subviews you added that are not being removed at dealloc time. Even though if its ARC enabled, sometimes in loops, some objects linger for longer and create some memory leaks. So using

```
@autorealease {}
```

autorelease snippet can help with those situations.

But Like I said we would need that code to determine exactly what is happening with your code. But my bet is that the issue is in there.(With the evidence you provided us).